# document.body.appendChild(script) vs eval()

Tags: javascript

I have the following two options to run a script with a string:

Option A:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = "function foo(){console.log('Hello!')}";
script.type = "text/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(script);
foo();
```

Option B:

```
eval("function foo(){console.log('Hello!')}");
foo();
```

They both print `Hello` in the console.

If I want to let users dynamically run scripts in my app, which one is a better(safer, faster) option?

Comment: I don't really think there is a *safer* option, personally i would use `eval()` as it require less lines of code. More about `eval` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Comment: whichever you prefer - they are both script injections and they are both equally safe\dangerous

Comment: You should first define your security concerns. What do you mean by safe? I may be wrong but I think you should not concern yourself with eval vs script. More importantly, you can achieve some level of security using [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to let users dynamically run scripts in my app ...

There's nothing safe with this requirement, and none of the options is [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) friendly.

The "*best*" approach you could use though is `Function`, 'cause at least that doesn't reaches/target the local scope, like `eval` would do, keeping the execution within its function body scope.

The question now would be how to make the code available to the user without interfering with the rest of the code, or the previous call, or the global scope.

For this specific case I suggest a *CommonJS* like approach, so that your users must define what they are exporting in their code.

**Example**

```
const CommonJS = code => {
  const exports = {};
  const module = {exports};
  const runtime = Function(
    'module', 'exports',
    `"use strict";${code};return module`
  );
  return runtime(module, exports);
};

const {exports} = CommonJS(`
  module.exports = function foo(){console.log('Hello!')}
`);

exports();
```

Using this approach your users can define a single, or multiple, exports, like in Node.js, becoming familiar with the CommonJS module system, and avoiding any sort of global scope pollution, thanks to the `"use strict"` directive and the Function closure itself.

Alternatively, you can `const foo = Function('return(' + code + ')')()` but that requires `code` to be a single expression, so I would personally stick with the previous approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I run `function foo(){console.log('Hello!')} function boo(){console.log('Meow!')}` and selectively call `foo()` or `boo()`?

Comment: `exports.foo = function foo() {}; exports.boo = function boo(){};` at that point you `const {foo, boo} = CommonJS(code).exports;` and you can invoke either function. With a bit of analysis you could loop over `exports` key and if it's just one, and it's a function, you invoke it right away, or adjust the logic accordingly with your needs.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could also add the full code that calls `foo()` and `boo()` as an `example2` in your post.

Comment: code: `function foo(){console.log('Hello!')} function boo(){console.log('Meow!')} module.exports = {foo, boo};` run it: `const {foo, boo} = CommonJS(code).exports; foo(); boo();`